# Print Nightmare patch missing for Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

`Windows Server 2016 Standard` servers seem to be unable to receive or see the PrintNightmare patch.

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-34527), I should be seeking KB5004948. According to [this Microsoft page on the KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/july-7-2021-kb5004948-os-build-14393-4470-out-of-band-fb676642-a3fe-4304-a79c-9d651d2f6550), it requires the latest SSU. I verified SSU KB5001402 was installed on the server.

However, Windows Update does not show KB5004948 as available. The server has no remaining hotfixes per Windows Update. Using `Get-Hotfix` in Powershell confirms it is not patched:

```
> Get-HotFix -Id KB5004948
Get-HotFix : Cannot find the requested hotfix on the 'localhost' computer. Verify the input and run the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-HotFix -Id KB5004948
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-HotFix], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetHotFixNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand
```

Downloading the direct MSU and attempting to install results in an unexpected `The update is not applicable to your computer.`

Is there something I am missing here? Is there a typo on the Microsoft page perhaps on which KB is the proper hotfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This update has been superseded by KB5004238 then by KB5005393 then by KB5005043. So, as of today, you should check if KB5005043 is installed.

You can see that information in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com), search for [KB5004948](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5004948), click on the update matching your OS and take a look at "Package Details" to see informations about supersedence:

[image: KB5004948 - Update details]